# python code to zip and download a folder with images

Tags: python, django, django-views, download, zip

I would like to download images that are uploaded in Django. Currently, I am zipping the folder and storing it in one of the Django folders first and then downloading it. After that, I delete the zipped folder which is in my Django app.

Is it possible to zip a folder and directly download it without saving it in my Django folder.

```
zip_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(project), str(project) + "_images.zip")

    def make_archive(source, destination):
        base = os.path.basename(destination)
        name = base.split('.')[0]
        format = base.split('.')[1]
        archive_from = os.path.dirname(source)
        archive_to = os.path.basename(source.strip(os.sep))
        # print(source, destination, archive_from, archive_to)
        shutil.make_archive(name, format, archive_from, archive_to)
        shutil.move('%s.%s' % (name, format), destination)

    make_archive(src_path, zip_path)

    file_path = zip_path
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/force-download") 
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            os.remove(file_path)
            if "selected" in request.POST:
                shutil.rmtree(src_path)
```

Comment: I think **zip a folder** is same as **creating a zip folder** and when you want to download that folder it has to be present somewhere in the filesystem. *You cannot Download something that doesn't exist.*

Comment: you should try to use `io.Bytes` to create file in memory. It is common method to send generated image (or other file) without saving on disk.